# Using custom application class for global variables in Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using a custom application class for storing my global variables but i don't seem to be able to get it to work.
here is my class :

```
    #if DEBUG
    [assembly: Application(Debuggable = true)]
    #else
    [assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
    #endif
    internal class MyApp : Application
    {

        private Customer loginedCustomer;
        private List<string> sefareshItems;
        public Boolean isOnline { set; get; }
        public MyApp(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            // If OnCreate is overridden, the overridden c'tor will also be called.
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public void SetLCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            loginedCustomer = customer;
        }

        public Customer GetLCustomer()
        {
            return loginedCustomer;
        }

        public void SetItems(List<string> items)
        {
            sefareshItems = items;
        }

        public List<string> GetItems()
        {
            return sefareshItems;
        } 

    }
```

and since i could find any documentation about using such class and by looking at the java examples both of these code gives me the "unable to cast from source to destination" exception

```
 MyApp m = (MyApp)Application;
```

and

```
Myapp m=(MyApp)ApplicationContext;
```

could you help me figure this out?
and i have another question.is it a good practice to get or set variables using methods or using a public static one?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application is a class definition.

You will need an instance of Application to cast as MyApp.

Make MyApp a static Class.

Make your method's static methods.

Then you can simply access Replace all references to Application with MyApp, and use it that way.

Comment: There is a property named Application there.i'm using that not the class definition

Comment: That's a static class definition, not a property. You can use the static methods and properties of the static class definition, but it itself is not an instance of class Application.

Comment: So if i have to make instance of my class in every activity how can i share the variables between them?

Comment: I would recommend creating a static class, with static properties for your variables. That will work the way you are wanting this to work.